# Convert SQL to Eloquent with agregate methods

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can I convert that SQL Query to Eloquent mode In Laravel 4 :

```
SELECT count(distinct(worker_id)) FROM formation_worker WHERE formation_id in(SELECT id FROM formations WHERE YEAR(start_date)=YEAR(now()))
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FormationWorker::select(DB::raw('count(distinct(worker_id))'))
    ->whereIn('formation', function($sq) {
        $sq->select('id')
           ->from('formations')
           ->whereRaw('YEAR(start_date)=YEAR(now())');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response.
But in my case I don't have a model for the pivot table.
Should I create it or there is another alternative ??

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based in @limonte reply :

```
DB::table('formation_worker')
                            ->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(worker_id))'))
                                ->whereIn('formation_id', function($sq) {
                                    $sq->select('id')
                                       ->from('formations')
                                       ->whereRaw('YEAR(start_date)=YEAR(now())');
                                })->first()
```

Comment: you asked for the Eloquent solution, this is the [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) solution :)